# Google Tag Manager with partytown in Astrojs not work

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, astrojs, partytown

I'm trying to setting gtm with partytown on astro but it's not working. I followed the documentation but the tags are not fired on my gtm and I also have some problems with CORS. If anyone has configured gtm with partytown on astro I would appreciate the help.

This is all my code:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script type="text/partytown">
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
    j.async = true;
    j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "GTM-ID");
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

My `astro.config.mjs`

```
 integrations: [
    tailwind(),
    react(),
    partytown({
      config: {
        forward: ['dataLayer.push']
      }
    })
  ],
```

[My gtm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ACaV.png)

[The console in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSNqV.png)

Comment: I suppose is:inline directive is not necessary since type="text/partytown" attribute is already there?

Comment: No I would add that..

Comment: if you put a console log inside the function you'll see that it never execute. At least that is what happened in my site. I ended up removing partytown for this tag. Waiting for the bug to be fixed

Comment: Any updates on this? I cannot make it work with my Astro project...